# Running php script (php function) in linux bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

How we run php script using Linux bash?

php file `test.php`

`test.php` contains:

```
<?php echo "hello\n" ?>
```

Comment: In addition to answers below, if you are using PHP short tags (`<? … ?>`) make sure they are enabled in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the command line, enter this:

```
php -f filename.php
```

Make sure that filename.php both includes and executes the function you want to test. Anything you echo out will appear in the console, including errors.

Be wary that often the php.ini for Apache PHP is different from CLI PHP (command line interface).

Reference: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php

Answer (score 33):

First of all check to see if your PHP installation supports CLI. Type: `php -v`. You can execute PHP from the command line in 2 ways:

1. `php yourfile.php`
2. `php -r 'print("Hello world");'`

Answer (score 22):

There are two ways you can do this. One is the one already mentioned, i.e.:

```
php -f filename.php
```

The second option is making the script executable (`chmod +x filename.php`) and adding the following line to the top of your .php file:

```
#!/path/to/php
```

I'm not sure though if a webserver likes this, so if you also want to use the .php file in a website, that might not be the best idea. Still, if you're just writing some kind of script, it is easier to type `./path/to/phpfile.php` than having to type `php -f /path/to/phpfile.php` every time.

Comment: The hash bang approach will only work if you make the permissions on the script executable

Comment: You can also run `which php > filename.php` then `chmod +x filename.php` then edit the file.

Comment: Note that @YzmirRamirez's comment will overwrite filename.php if it exists

Answer (score 4):

Simply this should do:

```
php test.php
```

Answer (score 4):

just run in linux terminal to get phpinfo .

```
   php -r 'phpinfo();'
```

and to run file like index.php

```
    php -f index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
php -f test.php
```

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) for full details of running PHP from the command line

Answer (score 1):

```
php test.php
```

should do it, or

```
php -f test.php
```

to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I was in need to decode URL in a Bash script. So I decide to use PHP in this way:

```sh
$ cat url-decode.sh
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
URL='url=https%3a%2f%2f1%2fecp%2f'
/usr/bin/php -r '$arg1 = $argv[1];echo rawurldecode($arg1);' "$URL"
```

Sample output:

```sh
$ ./url-decode.sh 
url=https://1/ecp/
```

Answer (score 1):

just to add another thing related to php and terminal: one way to play with php and test code immediately in the terminal is with

`php -a`

which will open an interactive php mode where you can test without having to open, save and run files. Its handy for figuring things out like new functions you've never used before.