# How to write a bash script that can parse through an XML file as input and remove certain elements from the file

Tags: xml, linux, bash, parsing

I need to create a bash script that manipulates the following sample xml file:

1. check for a particular ID and remove that XML branch for that ID.
2. the ID's are read from a text file.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <cmtf xmlns="urn:RM_UPMS_CMTFEnvelopeSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <data xmlns="">
   <entitygroup entityname="people">
     <PERSON xmlns="abc">
       <ID ns="">12280</ID>
       <PIN xmlns="">erererre</PIN>
       <NAME xmlns="">ereffdef</NAME>
     </PERSON>
     <PERSON xmlns="bbc">
       <ID ns="">5567</ID>
       <PIN xmlns="">erererre</PIN>
       <NAME xmlns="">ereffdef</NAME>
     </PERSON>
     <PERSON xmlns="bbc">
       <ID ns="">3347</ID>
       <PIN xmlns="">ededed</PIN>
       <NAME xmlns="">rtreer</NAME>
     </PERSON>
     <PERSON xmlns="bbc">
       <ID ns="">3249</ID>
       <PIN xmlns="">erererre</PIN>
       <NAME xmlns="">ereffdef</NAME>
     </PERSON>
   </entitygroup>
   </data>
   </cmtf>
   ```

Here, I need to remove all the `<PERSON>` tag for all the entries that have the ID 12280, 3249 which is being read from a text file.

Comment: `xml-sed`, part of `xml-coreutils` may be your friend to perform simple operations on XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use php like this: [running php script (php function) in linux bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549562/running-php-script-php-function-in-linux-bash)

And then you something like domdocument(http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to read and the right the xml.

Of course this is assumes you have php installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XSLT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for that. Create an xsl stylesheet which transform the input xml into the desired output. On the console you can use `xsltproc` (from `xmllint` package):

```
 xsltproc stylesheet.xsl input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This reads a series of IDs to delete from a file `input_file`, and creates an `output.xml` based on `input.xml` with those entries deleted:

```
ed_commands=( )
while read -r num_to_delete; do
  ed_commands+=( -d "//PERSON[./ID=$num_to_delete]"
done <input_file

xmlstarlet ed "${ed_commands[@]}" <input.xml >output.xml
```

Note that it requires [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).