# How to set up multiple cron jobs that run one after the other in PHP and Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, cron

I have a basic understanding of cron jobs, but I need something more complex now. I need to upload around 100 tables in to MySql, each table has around 500 MB data and then run some php cron jobs on each table, one table after the other. I explain it more detail below:

1. Upload table through load data local infile in php. Tables are to be uploaded from my directory which had CSV files. How do I create a loop to upload all these files?
2. Run script1.php, then script2.php then script3.php all three as cron jobs
3. Repeat step 1

Kindly let me know how to do this? I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Add them to a shell script then add the single shell script line to your cron file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script (e.g. bash) that does all of the work you want to do, including updloading the table data, running the php scripts, and repeating as needed.

Sample bash file (/home/spanky/stuffToDo.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Simple bash script that does some work

php -f dowork1.php
php -f dowork2.php
php -f dowork3.php
```

Set up your cron job to call that script as needed, something like this:

```
10 * * * * /home/spanky/stuffToDo.sh
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5549562/4669143) for more details about calling PHP functions from a bash script, particularly the answers which mention the use of CLI PHP for command-line use of PHP.

There are lots of solid examples out there that demonstrate using bash for this type of thing.  This is a great place to start:  https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Note: If each step absolutely must be a cron job, then you'll have to schedule them accordingly, understanding that they may overlap if one finishes late (or never finishes).  You could get into more complicated scenarios where one cronjob that relies on the completion of a previous job will check a status flag or file before proceeding, but that gets messy quickly.

Comment: Can you just explain what to write exactly in the bash script or point to some resource where I can learn?

Comment: I expanded my answer to include a sample bash script and a link to a good introductory bash tutorial.

Comment: To run the scripts one after other in sequence we have to add && between the scripts right?

Comment: Pls check my updated question about loading all CSV files in my directory through a for loop. How to do this is bash script?